# Basis of body centered cubic latice

Tags: solid-state-physics, geometry, crystals

For the past few days I've been studying solid state physics and more specifically I have been busy with the crystal structures. I was just making some exercices and on of them asked me to give the basis for the body centered cubic lattice as well as some primitive lattice vectors. The primitive vectors I used where
$$\vec{a}_1 = (1,0,0) \qquad \vec{a}_2 = (0,1,0) \qquad \vec{a}_3 = (1/2,1/2,1/2).$$
From this I deduced the basis would just be (0,0,0) since using these three vectors we could get any point is the lattice if we use integer coëfficients. However my textbook said that the basis would be (0,0,0) for the corners of the lattice and (1/2, 1/2, 1/2) for the center. I'm confused now since to mee the (1/2,1/2,1/2) seems unnecessary in this case. Does anyone know how to clear this up for me? Any help would be grealty appreciated :))

Comment: Maybe your book is suggesting 3 primitive vectors for simple cubic lattice. And a basis for the position of the centre of the cube. The vectors that you have chosen form a Bravais lattice and don't need a basis.

Comment: It is indeed an abuse of the word "primitive". We are all lazy, professors most lazy of all, and if your unit cell is perfectly cubic, we would have the least amount of work to do to get the Brillouin zone. So we take the basis as the pair. If you tried to find a primitive BCC unit cell with the basis being just one atom, then you would have to work really hard for the Brillouin zone.

Answer (score 0):

Preferably the primitive vectors should give the smallest volume given by :

$$V=|\vec{a_1}\cdot 
 (\vec{a_2} \times \vec{a_3})|$$

You can easily check that your set of primitive vectors does not give a smaller volume compare to the set in your book :

$$\vec{a}_1 = (1/2,1/2,-1/2) \qquad \vec{a}_2 = (-1/2,1/2,1/2) \qquad \vec{a}_3 = (1/2,-1/2,1/2)$$

No matter where the basis is.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks you for two things. One is the basis for the BCC unit cell. This means you have as unit cell a cube with side a ( or 1)  and the basis has two nodes, at (0, 0,0) and (1/2,1/2,1/2). This is not a primitive cell. Sometimes is called conventional cell. It easily shows the cubic symmetry of the lattice.
The second part is to find a unit cell. The unit cell is not unique but the one suggested by M06-2x is the one usually used when calculating the reciprocal lattice or structure factors. The unit cell does not need a base if you are just looking at lattices made from mathematical points. If the conventional cell has a volume of 1 for two nodes, any unit cell should have half that volume, so 1/2 in this case. Both yours and the usual one (mentioned above) satisfy this condition.